# How to configure WebPack to support "global.window" for Breeze-Client+DataJS

Tags: webpack, breeze, datajs

I am trying to convert a project from SystemJS to WebPack which is using breeze-client and datajs (for OData support). In total, this is an angular2 application, so breeze-bridge-angular2 is also part of the project.

While the SystemJS version runs fine, the WebPack version throws an error:

> Unable to initialize OData.  Needed to support remote OData

Apparently, the issue is that breeze-client is unable to find the OData library in global.window.OData. Some quick debugging shows that the root cause appears to be that "global.window" is generally undefined (in function __requireLibCore). Note that datajs is appears to be correctly included in webpack, so the issue is not a missing datajs, rather breeze-client not being able to access "window" in general.

[image: Debug Details]

I am pretty new to the entire topic, so I am struggling to identify the correct solution. I believe *something* needs to be configured in webpack to make this work, but I am not sure what this something could be - my apologies for being vague here - perhaps some imports-loader or ProvidePlugin reference in webpack.config.js.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: try using ProvidePlugin. it makes variable available at global level

Comment: As stated, that is what I am guessing. However, I have no clue what exactly to put into ProvidePlugin to make this specific case work. To make things more complicated, breeze-client does not access "window.OData" statically, but window[libName] with libName="OData".

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and used webpacks importsloader to solve this issue. It allows you to inject a variable into a module. More info [here](https://github.com/webpack/imports-loader)

Heres the snippet from my webpack config:

```
        { test: require.resolve('breeze-client/breeze.debug'), loader: 'imports-loader?this=>window,global=>{window: this}'},
```